# Can I add translated subtitles to a video licensed with a CC-BY-NC-ND?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

If I take a video that is

Creative Commons 3.0: Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs

Can I add translated subtitles to it and post it? I'm not sure if that would be considered to be remixing it or not.

Comment: Assuming that it *does* constitute a remix (and would therefore not be allowed under the terms of the licence) you can still do what you'd do with a more typical "All Rights Reserved" work, *i.e.* contact the copyright holder. They should (by, effectively, giving you a copy under difference licence terms) be able to give you permission to add subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

### No

Adding subtitles is creating a derivative work and this is specifically forbidden.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not because strictly speaking overlaying subtitles onto a piece of media is creating a derivative work.

However I would suggest bundling the video with a .srt subtitle file. Most media players will be able to play a .srt file to put subtitles on a video during playback

Comment: The combination would still constitute a derivative work, and the attempt at a run-around of the license would be evidence that the infringement was wilful, opening up higher damages.